# How to write a whole string to a file in Python and where does the file go?

Tags: python, string, file, format

I am doing an assignment on text formatting and alignment (text wrapping) and I need to write my formatted string to new file. But once I have written to the file (or think I've written) where does that file go? Does it actually create a file on my desktop or am I being stupid?

This is my code:

```
txtFile = open("Output.txt", "w")
txtFile.write(string)
txtFile.close()

return txtFile
```

Cheers,

JT

Comment: `return txtFile` is probably unnecessary, unless you're planning to do anything with the `file` object.

Comment: @Adam Is there actually anything you can do with a closed file object even if you wanted? Bug waiting to happen yes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is written to a file called "Output.txt" in your working directory (which is usually the directory from which the script has been executed).

To display the working directory, you can use:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/adam'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file without specifying a file path, the file will be created in the python scripts [`working directory`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Usually that is the location of your script but there are times when it may be a [different place](https://superuser.com/questions/396394/how-do-i-set-an-executables-working-directory-via-the-command-line-prior-to-ex).

The [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module in python will provide functions for checking and changing the working directory within python itself.
most notably:

```
os.chdir(path)
os.fchdir(fd)
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: ...without specifying an _absolute_ path.  Even if a path is given, it will be relative to the working directory unless it is absolute (starts with `/`).

Comment: I was thinking more of scheduled tasks / self executed tasks, etc etc. There are plenty of ways to change the default working directory both outside and inside the python script.

Answer (score 1):

It will create a new file called "Output.txt" in the same directory that you executed your script from.  It may mean that the file can't be written to, if you're in a directory that doesn't have the appropriate permissions for your user.